# How to create seal code for own website?

Tags: html

I want to create seal code exactly like Godaddy, Paypal and other companies issues to their customers to paste that code on to their websites.

Comment: What is "seal code"? You mean the "verified by [Certificate Authority]" banners? Then... verify your site using [Certificate Authority Of Your Choice].

Comment: I don't know why people close or vote down a question with out given a solid description. I request to Stackoverflow team to fix it so that no one could do next time.

Comment: Well, for most people (including me), what you ask is really obvious. So they think you are trying to insult them by asking such things. But that does not make the question invalid, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...

1. Get your designer to draw a shiny badge
2. Save that badge on your website
3. ```
   <a href="http://yoursite.com" alt="Certified by MyCompany">
      <img src="http://yoursite.com/your_shiny_badge.jpg" />
   </a>
   ```

   :)